# Adding an item to a dojo store using 'before' option

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

I've got a dijit/Tree connected to a dijit/Tree/ObjectStoreModel which is in turn connected to a dojo/store/Memory wrapped in dojo/store/Observable - essentially as per the example on the dijit/tree documentation.

It's working mostly fine: I preload the store with some objects and can add other objects in using store.add(item).  The data is hierarchical and that also is working by setting the parent property on each item added to the store.

However, I want to be able to specify how within a parent sub items should be ordered.  e.g. if I've got an item with id "parent_1" and I add two items (say, "item_A", "item_B") both with parent set to "parent_1" then I'll end up with:

> parent_1
>
> - item_A
> - item_B

However, I want item_B to be placed above item_A.

store.add supports a second parameter: an object of properties, one of which is 'before'.  My understanding is that when you set 'before' to another object in the store, it should be placed before it.  so, when I add item_B I use:

```
var item_A = store.get("item_A");
var item_B = { id: "item_B", parent: "parent_1", ... };
store.add(item_B, { before: item_A });
```

However, it's not working.  item_B is always simply appended at the end.  Does anyone know how to make this work?  Thanks!

Comment: How did you deal with this? I'm trying got do the exact same thing. Can you share your experience?

Comment: I'm sorry to report that I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. The patches submitted under this ticket don't seem to work either - https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15660.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/Memory.js), it doesn't look as if dojo/store/Memory supports the `before` PutDirective.

If you want this feature, I suspect you will have to submit a Dojo feature request, or patch/augment dojo/store/Memory to provide the function you require.

Comment: Thanks for answering and particularly for linking to the source.  I never thought to read the source before (I've just been using the docs / api reference on the dojo site along with a hefty amount of trial and error) but this looks like it could be very useful!